# Transform rows to columns in Spark Scala SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a database table containing unique user ids and items clicked.
e.g.

user id,item id
1 , 345
1 , 78993
1 , 784
5, 345
5, 897
15, 454

and I want to transform this data into following format using spark SQL (if possible in Scala)

user id, item ids
1, 345, 78993, 784
5, 345,897
15, 454

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty simple `groupByKey` scenario. Although if you want to do something else with it after, then I would suggest using a more efficient `PairRDDFunction` as `groupByKey` is inefficient for follow up queries.

Answer (score 1):

A local example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


object Main extends App {

  case class Record(user: Int, item: Int)

  val items = List(
    Record(1 , 345),
    Record(1 , 78993),
    Record(1 , 784),
    Record(5, 345),
    Record(5, 897),
    Record(15, 454)
  )

  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local"))
  val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
  import hiveContext.implicits._
  import hiveContext.sql

  val df = sc.parallelize(items).toDF()
  df.registerTempTable("records")
  sql("SELECT * FROM records").collect().foreach(println)

  sql("SELECT user, collect_set(item) From records group by user").collect().foreach(println)
}
```

This produces:

```
[1,ArrayBuffer(78993, 784, 345)]
[5,ArrayBuffer(897, 345)]
[15,ArrayBuffer(454)]
```